# Real Time Analysis And Sentiment Analysis

Tags: java, python, twitter, real-time, sentiment-analysis

My project is to do the prediction by doing sentiment analysis of tweets(Cricket).
I will gather tweets as stream. 
For this I need to do real time analysis of tweets and then sentiment analysis of tweets.
I'm using Kafka and Spark Streaming.

How to do real time analysis of tweets using kafka? I need those tweets which is related to cricket 
After real time analysis how to do Sentiment Analysis of tweets using spark streaming?

Can you please tell me which language is best to do this whole task, Python or java?

Comment: python is best for analysis

Answer (score 0):

I suggest go with python
gathering tweets as stream - use Kafka : https://www.rittmanmead.com/blog/2017/01/getting-started-with-spark-streaming-with-python-and-kafka/

For real time analysis on the tweets, you will need nltk, word2vec or some natural language processing api: https://github.com/ankitagarwal/nltk_kafka_twitter

https://github.com/emumba-com/live_twitter_sentiment_analysis

I hope this gives you a kick start for your task.